# React loop through json object and display data

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-read-json?file=index.tsx)

I have a simple json file that I'm importing and I would like to loop through and output the json data in a div

I'll probable want to pick out parts of the json but for now I just need to be able to output the json

Do I need to create an array from the json data and then map over that.

```
const showProductData = Object.keys(ProductData).map(function(key) {
  return <div>{ProductData[key]}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>JSON</h2>
      {showProductData}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your demo gives a very clear error message - `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ProductSize, ProductHeight, ProductWeight}`.  What is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass objects as React child. You can convert however the objects to string then print it:

```
const showProductData = Object.keys(ProductData).map(function(key) {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(ProductData[key])}</pre>;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As you might have noticed you cannot output objects directly. Your current code results in:

> Error in /turbo_modules/react-dom@16.8.0/cjs/react-dom.development.js (46:29)
>
> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ProductSize, ProductHeight, ProductWeight}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

To output an object you need to convert it to a string first. This can be done with for example with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
/* import React, { Component } from "react";                                                                                            */const{Component}=React;/*
 * import { render } from "react-dom";                                                                                                  */const{render}=ReactDOM;/*
 * import "./style.css";                                                                                                                */(()=>{const style=document.createElement("style");style.innerHTML="h1,p{font-family:Lato}*{font-family:sans-serif}";document.head.appendChild(style)})();/*
 *
 * import ProductData from "./product.json";                                                                                            */const ProductData={"default":{"ProductSize":{"min":32},"ProductHeight":{"min":15},"ProductWeight":50},"ProductOne":{"ProductSize":{"min":20,"max":15},"ProductHeight":{"min":50,"max":87},"ProductSpacing":90,"ProductWeight":100},"ProductTwo":{"ProductSize":{"min":43,"max":67},"ProductHeight":{"min":12,"max":78},"ProductSpacing":34,"ProductWeight":56},"ProductThree":{"ProductSize":{"min":67,"max":90},"ProductHeight":{"min":12,"max":34},"ProductSpacing":67,"ProductWeight":78}};/*
 */

const showProductData = Object.keys(ProductData).map(function(key) {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(ProductData[key])}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>JSON</h2>
      {showProductData}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>                                                                                                              <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```